# How do I indicate that a Generic container can be heterogeneous?

Tags: python, types

Say I want to create a custom class and make use of contained type hinting like in `list[int]`. As I understand I would do that like:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyContainer(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, ls: list[T]):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, ix: int) -> T:
        pass
```

But does this now imply it's a homogeneous container? Do I have to do anything special to use it like (`c = MyContainer(['a', 1])`)?

Comment: I'd also appreciate it if someone could help me clean up my language. I'm pretty sure I'm using some words incorrectly.

Comment: I think in `c = MyContainer(['a', 1])` the type of the list can be considered to be `list[str | int]`, so my first guess is that this should be fine. I didn't test it though.

Comment: It's only as homogeneous as `list` is, which is only as homogeneous as you want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c = MyContainer(['a', 1])` doesn't make any actual use of Generics (type is defaulted to `Any`). You need to pass type parameter for `MyContainer`, to tell what is the actual type variable to be used in place of `T`. For example:

```
c = MyContainer[str](['a', 1])
```

This will obviously trigger type checker to issue a warning:

```
Argument of type "list[str | int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "ls" of type "list[str]" in function "__init__"
  "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "str"
```

So, now it's a matter of correctly telling your class what you actually want to have in place of a type generic.
If you want to accept strings and ints but nothing else, typing it as:

```
c = MyContainer[str | int](['a', 1])
```

will work just fine.